# HERE map connect three flexiblePolyline or avoid dividing routing v8 response then is transit

Tags: polyline, heremaps

Here map I am begging you for help. Please answer me. I know that you answer really rarely, but please, answer this time. I need either that the answer from the backend routing V8 does not divide the route into an additional section when there is a transit (sections are only created by origin, via, and destination sent in the query) or, if this is not possible, how to combine several flexiblePolyline into one.

I am begging you again for an answer

Answer (score 0):

You may consider decoding the multiple polylines into coordinate pairs to combine to work with, and if needed, encode to a single polyline.
This link is HERE's KB article on polyline decode with sample code for several languages:
https://support.here.com/csm?id=kb_article_csm&sys_id=914753c31b77f41015e297d4bd4bcb33&sysparm_rank=2&sysparm_tsqueryId=3d6d34e11b0a15106b12ea0dad4bcba6